# How to ignore helpfiles in a *.txt autocmd

Tags: vimrc

In the following autocmd:

```
" Default filetype, color if unrecognized (like a text file to write notes)
augroup DefaultFiletype
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufRead, BufNewFile *.txt set ft=markdown
    autocmd BufRead, BufNewFile *.txt colorscheme OceanicNext
augroup END
```

Is there a pattern or way that I can target `*.txt` files that are not help files? If so, how could this be done? I suppose something that is not in the path `*/vim/*` would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check how the stock Vim runtimes do this detection, with:

```
:au BufRead *.txt
--- Autocommands ---
filetypedetect  BufRead
    *.txt     if getline('$') !~ 'vim:.*ft=help'|   setf text| endif
```

So you could use this same recipe to set the filetype to `markdown` only for the `*.txt` files that are not help files.

Also note that `colorscheme` is a global command and it will affect the colors for all buffers (and also elements in Vim not belonging to buffers.) It might not be advisable to switch colorschemes when opening specific file types.

Comment: cool, yea I'll check based on `expand('<afile>')` then, as in the above it's checking the last line, and vim help has something like: `vim:tw=78:sw=4:ts=8:noet:ft=help:norl:` at the end.